# Changing SOMAXCONN value in MAC OS

Tags: macos, boost-asio

My ASIO library based code in OSX is using 'listen backlog queue' size equal to the value SOMAXCONN.
This macro is defined in SDK inside /usr/include/sys/Socket.h

I think changing the sdk files is not the correct way. So, how should I redefine this to a higher value?

I tried redefining it inside main file of my project but xcode emits warning 'macro redefinition' and only old value is used by ASIO library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no other option but to make the change inside `/usr/include/sys/Socket.h`